# Bug Wordpress / Calendly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, calendly

i have a problem with my Calendly on my website on mobile version (No problem on PC).
When i am on mobile, the page for scheduling is half the size it should be (look at the screen).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCDZ3.jpg)

I tried pretty much everything (change the schedule from place, from page, take the schedule of another friend, play with the height etc...) and nothing worked.
The schedule page of Calendly is still half of the size it should be which is a big problem for the customer who wills truggle to schedule a meet with me. Btw i tried all the addons of Calendly and there is the same bug. Thanks you

Comment: A commercial product, Calendly is. Why not address your question to their support staff?

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved the answer was to add this on the aditionnal CSS:

```
.calendly-inline-widget,
.calendly-inline-widget iframe {
    min-height: 700px !important;
}
```